# extracting strings out of one long string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this really long string and I would like to extract specific strings out of it in a list form.

the string:

```
[#<User id: 1, login: "test", hash ... ]
```

I would like to extract everything that appears in between `login: "` and `",` so in this case it would be the word `test`. This string can be indefinitely long but the pattern will be the same. How can I go about extracting the words out in a list form?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
string.scan(/login: "(.*?)",/)
```